# Query that join two tables, shows all rows from first table and from second only the row that has the date bigger than today and closer to today

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `partners` and `tasks`. I would like to write a query that shows all the partners and if there are tasks show only one >= than today (date). It is important that the task is the immediately next to today as date, not the first >= than today that is in the db.

Please find the tables and code below. My problem is that the query does not return the immediately next value to the inserted date, but returns the >= that find in the database.

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE partners 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    code INTEGER,
    name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tasks 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    code INTEGER,
    comment TEXT,
    data INTEGER
);

-- insert some values
INSERT INTO partners VALUES (1, 222, 'M');
INSERT INTO partners VALUES (2, 333, 'F');
INSERT INTO partners VALUES (3, 555, 'F-m');

INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (1, 333, 'f', 2020 );
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (2, 333, 'f', 2022 );
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (3, 333, 'f', 2021 );
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (4, 333, 'f-i', 2023 );
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (5, 222, 'm', 2021 );
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (6, 444, 'F', 2025 );

-- fetch some values
SELECT * 
FROM partners 
LEFT JOIN tasks ON partners.code = tasks.code 
WHERE tasks.data >= '2021'
GROUP BY tasks.code
ORDER BY tasks.data ASC;
```

Desired Result / Query Output:

```
1 , 222, M, m, 2021
2 , 333, F, f, 2021
3 , 555, F-m, No Task
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the result you want with the sample data as table and add the tag for the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Please define "appropriate".  Also, your query is broken because the `GROUP BY` columns are inconsistent with the `SELECT` columns.

Comment: @stickybit Hi, Thank you for your reply, i have added the DBMS, it is phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi Gordon, Thank you for your help, I was wrong using appropriate, I would like to say immediately next or same value. Example 1, 2, 4, 5   If my date (today) is 3 the query should provide 4, not any value bigger than 3.

Comment: @Andrei: phpMyAdmin isn't a DBMS. It's just a client. But it is either used with MySQL or MariaDB. Which one do you really use?

Comment: @stickybit Hi Sticky, I will use MySQL. Thank You!